# Creating a duplicate label in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis-3, labeling, editing

In QGIS 3.4 I'm creating a set of ten maps (layouts) from one QGIS project, and each map centres over a particular polygon. In each layout I shift the map to centre it on the page or to fit as best as possible. From that polygon layer I create labels, and I then get one label for each polygon. I can use the tools to manipulate these labels as required, as the labels need to be moved a bit here and there.
  Is it possible to select a label and duplicate that label and have the duplicate locked in the map to another place? This is so I can move the duplicate to the best place for individual map, keeping the original where it was for the previous map. What I can do in ArcGIS: create an annotation layer from labels and then have full control of over that text (copy, resize etc) and have the text locked to the map where I want it - Well I would like to do that in QGIS as easily as I can in Arc. Is this possible?

Comment: You can lock the layers and their styles for a map canvas in the composer after aligning everything as you need it.

Comment: Thanks! How about having editing control over label text after it has been generated? On one map I might want to show the label text "Cubbington & Leek Wootton" with "Cubbington &" on one line, and "Leek Wootton" on the 2nd, and in another map "Cubbington" on it's own line etc. Can you select a label and then have control over how that individual label is shown? Would it best just to put the labels in as map elements (such as I do with a title etc) were I know I have control over them - with the exception of having that text locked to the map, which in those cases I really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

i am not really sure i understand your question, but it seems i had a similar problem: a large qgis project with different print layouts each representing a different print frame of a collection of 4 maps. layouts would overlap for about one inch, and i had to manually move the labels so that they would not be cut by any layout border. i have solved this problem by either moving the label on frame 1 or frame 2 only, and paid attention not to cut the labels placed in the overlapping strip, by moving them at the center of the strip so that they could be fully legible in both layouts. a different, less elegant solution would be to place the majority of labels, then duplicate the label layer and personalize them for each layout. you would end up with labels layer 1 on when you are working on layout 1, a similar but not identical label layer 2 when working on layout 2 and so on... keep in mind that you have the option to save the label placement info within the qgis project or in the layer file (old style method by adding additional columns for x and y position), you will probably need the latter in this case.

Comment: Thanks. How do I duplicate the lable layer?

Comment: right click on the layer > duplicate layer